# How to Debug gremlin groovy script when load data to Titan

Tags: groovy, titan, gremlin

I'm new to titan and groovy. I wrote a groovy script to load data to titan, executed with `./bin/gremlin.sh -e load.groovy`. When this script is running, it always throws Exception. Has there a way to debug when running gremlin groovy script? I'm really exhausted to write `printf` everywhere.
Or another way to load data to titan with debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the code you wrote in that file is in Groovy language (except few add-ons methods). You could use any IDE to run supporting Groovy to run this code.

Remember that you might have to exchange few code like `:remote ..` with `TitanFactory.open(..)`.

Comment: if wrote as this way,  how to load gremlin's library. i have try wrote in Java, init with `graph = TitanFactory.open(...)` but found that it taken 5 min to initial graph object, so slow…maybe remote debug and ssh forward server's  port had wasted a lot of time.Finally finished this debug by add `println`, and executed by `./bin/gremlin.sh -e load.groovy` step by step. I don't know why use `gremlin-groovy` only takes about  `10s`， but  jave takes `5min`

Comment: What do you pass to `TitanFactory.open(..)`?

Comment: `BaseConfiguration`  

    -  storage.backend  
    
    -  storage.hostname  
    -  storage.hbase.table  
    -  schema.default